# SQL How to combine 2 queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 queries that return results pertaining to trade debtors. The first returns amounts per month for all trade debtors while the second returns amounts per month for all trade debtors after 30 days.

1st query

```
SELECT  T2.Name AS Period, 
        SUM(T1.LineTotal) AS CurrentAmount, 
        MAX(T0.DocRate) AS ExchangeRate 
FROM    OINV T0 INNER JOIN 
        INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry  INNER JOIN 
        dbo.OFPR AS t2 ON T1.FinncPriod = T2.AbsEntry  
WHERE   T0.DocStatus = 'O' AND t0.DocDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-01'
GROUP BY    T2.Name
```

2nd query

```
SELECT  T2.Name AS Period, 
        SUM(T1.LineTotal) AS NonCurrentAmount,         
        MAX(T0.DocRate) AS ExchangeRate 
FROM    OINV T0 INNER JOIN 
        INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry  INNER JOIN 
        dbo.OFPR AS t2 ON T1.FinncPriod = T2.AbsEntry  
WHERE   T0.DocStatus = 'O' AND DATEDIFF(day,t0.DocDate,t0.DocDueDate)>30 
        AND t0.DocDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-01' 
GROUP BY    T2.Name
```

How do I combine the 2 queries above into one such that the resulting query will return results in 4 columns; `Period, CurrentAmount, NonCurrentAmount and exchange rate.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the difference in `where` clause to a `case` statement:

```
SELECT  T2.Name AS Period, 
        SUM(T1.LineTotal) AS CurrentAmount, 
        MAX(T0.DocRate) AS ExchangeRate1, 
        SUM(case when DATEDIFF(day,t0.DocDate,t0.DocDueDate) > 30
            then T1.LineTotal end) AS NonCurrentAmount,         
        MAX(case when DATEDIFF(day,t0.DocDate,t0.DocDueDate) > 30
            then T0.DocRate end) AS ExchangeRate2
FROM    OINV T0
JOIN    INV1 T1 
ON      T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
JOIN    dbo.OFPR AS t2 ON T1.FinncPriod = T2.AbsEntry  
WHERE   T0.DocStatus = 'O'
        AND t0.DocDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-01'
GROUP BY
        T2.Name
```

Comment: +1 : Except that, I'd leave the `t0.DocDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-01'` in the WHERE clause as it applied to both queries.  The first `SUM()` and `MAX()` would then not need the `CASE` statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andomar and Dems.